# Permanently set PGDATA environment variable Mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, shell

To start my Postgres server I need to run these commands:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
export PGDATA='/usr/local/var/postgres'
```

Isn't there a way to define the PGDATA permanently and from there on only use commands like `pg_ctl start` to operate in the shell? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're half way there. The only thing you might want to do is to get `PGDATA` whenever you open the terminal by adding the `export` line to your shell config file. On my macOS machine i added the following line:
`export PGDATA='/Users/john/.postgres'` to `~/.bash_profile` file. Don't forget to source it if you want to see the effect immediately by executing `. ~/.bash_profile` command. That's it from now on you can start your posters server by simply typing `pg_ctl start`. Hope it was worth the wait for the answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

`export` will set the context for your current session. So we need to hack our terminal so that we will export this `PGDATA` env variable to every session.

If you are using `zsh`, you can simply execute the below command.

`echo "export PGDATA='/usr/local/var/postgres'" >> ~/.zshrc`

In case you are not using `zsh` replace `~/.zshrc` in the above command with `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`

then, do `source ~/.zshrc` to see the immediate effect. You can instantly check using `echo $PGDATA` command.

Whenever you open a new terminal, your environment variable will be available by default.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Users can try this:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services.
2. Manually start the PostgreSQL Database Server Service and set change Startup type to Automatic.